# Apt-cache: How to list all installed packages with version number?

Tags: debian, aptitude

`apt-cache dump --installed` doesn't work, it lists uninstalled packages as well.

I want to list the install packages each by one line, with the installed version number.

Comment: [bug #775771](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=775771) restrict apt-cache search results to installed packages

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try `dpkg -l`

it lists you the packages, version and a short description.

Comment: I like also `apt-show-versions` since it also shows which one is `uptotdate`.

Answer (score 39):

The simplest way is using [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=dpkg), but it might show a few extraneous packages and it truncates long package names and version numbers:

```
dpkg -l
```

To list only correctly installed packages and not truncate names:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii'
```

To get more control over the output format, you can use [`dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=dpkg-query):

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${status} ${package} ${version}\n' | \
sed -n 's/^install ok installed //p'
```

Answer (score 13):

Other command can be:

```
apt-show-versions
```

It also gives you info about the package state (up to date, upgradable, ...) and about the origin distribution (wheezy, jessie, ...). One can easily filter out packages which came from backports or other exotic repositories.

This program is packaged separately. Install it first with:

```
apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

Comment: This is really nice as it shows the version that a package could be upgraded to. +1.

Comment: combined with `apt-mark showmanual` this gives you a nice and easy way to retrieve versions of all manually installed packages, see also [this Askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages/492343#492343)
`apt-mark showmanual > /tmp/versions && apt-show-versions | grep -f /tmp/versions`

Answer (score 5):

The following command lists the packages with their versions, *and additionally* it lets you set up a system with the same packages and versions later, using the `pkg-selections.txt` file generated here:

```
aptitude -q -F "%?p=%?V %M" --disable-columns search \~i > pkg-selections.txt
```

Each line will contain package name, version and an optional "A" if the package was installed automatically.

Source: "[Cloning a Debian system - identical packages and versions](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/669/)". Also contains the script that sets up a system from `pkg-selections.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

To list the names of each installed package, type as any user:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

You will get an output like this :

```
accountsservice              install
aclinstall                   install
acpi-supportinstall          install
acpidinstall                 install
...
```

To remove the unecessary "install" character string, you can use *sed* :

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed 's:install$::'
```

And if yout want to save it to a file called *InstalledPackages*, you type this :

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed 's:install$::' > InstalledPackages
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have access to live system, and have a backup of root`/` partition, you can :

> `root@backup_server /mnt/old_root/var/lib/dpkg/info # ls -la *.list | awk {'print $9'}| sed 's/.list//' >> /root/installed_app`

Now this `/root/installed_app` contain all installed packages!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question years later, like I did:

- With `apt` you can do `apt list --installed` for a pretty printed list.
- `dpkg-query -W` without any formating options gives you `package name` and `version`.
- `sed -En 's/^(Package|Version): //p' /var/lib/dpkg/status | paste - -` Will give you the same output as above. This works without debian/ubuntu tools (say Ubuntu rootfs is mounted from RHEL).